Can every 2-player-coalition avoid losing in 5-player-nim?
I'm interested in $5$-player nim (it will become clear why $5$). Individual players - which I'll identify with the numbers from $1$ to $5$ - make moves as usual, with the move order going $... \rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow ...$ (but the starting player is not determined ahead of time). A nonempty proper subset $S$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is a winning coalition iff there is some choice of strategies for the players in $S$ such that, no matter who goes first and no matter what moves the players outside $S$ move, if the players in $S$ use their strategy then the first player to have no legal move will not be in $S$. (Note that there is no "winning player" as such, only a losing player. But "non-losing coalition" doesn't roll off the tongue as well.)
Say that a nim board (= initial setup of piles of stones) is strange if every $2$-element set of players is a winning coalition. (Obviously some $1$-element set of players must not be a winning coalition, and $5$ is the smallest set of players where $2$-element coalitions are strictly less than half of the total players.)

Question: do strange nim boards exist?

I've done a quick computer search that's turned up nothing, but that search was limited to boards with at most five piles and at most six stones per pile (and even then it only partially searched that gamespace).

@usul: if I understand correctly, there is no designated winner, just a designated loser. So if ${1,2}$ and ${3,4}$ are both winning and happen to play their respective strategies, then $5$ is bound to lose.

Maybe the title should reflect the intention by saying can every 2-player coalition avoid losing?

@AnthonyQuas Fair enough, updated!

Thanks Noah and @FlorianLehner, of course. Deleting my comment, not primarily out of embarrassment, but to avoid future confusion.

Ok, I guess strange boards do not exist for 6 or any even number of players, because any nim board is either a win for the odd player or the even player, so a coalition that only plays on even rounds (respectively, odd rounds) cannot guarantee to win.

@usul: How do you define strange for six players? Still coalitions of size two? I don't see why there a strange board could not exist.

@Noah Is your question equivalent to the following: Two players play NIM such that one makes two moves, while the other makes three moves in each five-move cycle, with a fixed order in each cycle. Is there a starting position which is losing for the 3-move player for any fixed order?

@domotorp Re: your question to me, yes. Re: your question to usul, the point is that - on an arbitrary board - by the usual 2-player nim analysis either ${1,3,5}$ or ${2,4,6}$ is a winning coalition; if the former is winning then a fortiori ${2,4}$ can't be winning, and if the latter is winning then a fortiori ${1,3}$ can't be winning.

Why? For example, {2,4} might be able to force 6 to lose.

@domotorp No, because then ${6,1}$ e.g. wouldn't be a winning coalition.

I meant that {2,4} can force 6 to lose IF {1,3,5} are against them. If 1 is helping 6, that's a different matter. But now I think that I can see the argument. It works because 2 divides 6, so we can make 3 pairs which obviously cannot be all winning. But I still believe that the comment above by usul makes no sense at all as it is worded.

There are boards where every 3-player coalition can avoid losing (I believe 3 piles of sufficiently large size is an example); is there a trivial reason why these must exist? More generally, if $n < 2k$ is there always a board such that every $k$-player coalition can avoid losing in $n$-player nim?

I think any board where all pile sizes are at least 3 and the number of piles is divisible by 3 is such an example; it is easy to prove by induction that these are good. Probably for answering the original question, it would be enough to give some similar conditions when we also allow 1/2-size piles. This seems doable with a careful analysis.

Disclaimer: at the moment this is a partial answer since at least one key claim is unsubstantiated, despite being heavily suggested by computational evidence. Subject to updates if I manage to find a reasonable explanation.
Some notation points: we assume that between moves the players' indices are rotated such that the player $1$ is always next on the move (after the move $1$ becomes $5$, $5$ becomes $4$ and so on). We write $ab$ for player coalitions $\{a, b\}$, and $a^x b^y \ldots$ to denote boards "$x$ heaps of size $a$, $y$ heaps of size $b$, ..." I expect there to be no confusion between coalitions and nim boards.
Answer: I'm strongly convinced strange boards do not exist, and further, no board is simultaneously winning for coalitions $12, 23, 34, 45$. I was not able to find any kind of high-level strategic argument, and the perhaps the reasoning below is somewhat unspectacular (not to mention, incomplete at the time). For the computer evidence I have, I struggle to present it in a way that would be suitable in a human-readable explanation, and invite anyone interested to replicate my findings independently.
It is worth noting that, after generalizing to arbitrary DAG games, strange configurations do exist (see bottom of this answer), implying that the result is, at least to some extent, nim-specific, and abstract game-theoretic arguments are unlikely to exist.
Claim. No nim-board is winning simultaneously for coalitions $12, 23, 34, 45$.
We start by enumerating winning boards for the coalition $45$. Intuititevely, $45$'s actions are subtantially more limited than $123$'s, at least for boards with high degree of freedom. Running a computer analysis for boards of (up to) 10 heaps of size (up to) 10 yields the following:
Sub-claim 1. All boards winning for $45$ are of the form $1^{5k} + A$, where $A \in \{-, 1, 2, 1^2, 2^4, 2^33, 1^42, 1^43, 1^32^2, 1^32^5, 1^32^43, 1^22^6, 1^42^5\}$.
Limited to boards of the form $1^x2^y3^z$ with $y \leq 6, z \leq 1$, one can properly establish this by computer-assisted induction (again, I wasn't able to find any kind of nice argument). There should be general arguments for why boards containing $2^7$, $3^2$ or a heap $x \geq 4$ are always losing for $45$, although I believe those are likely to contain high amount of case analysis as well.
If we subscribe to believing Sub-claim 1, proving the rest amounts to finite amount of computation, which yields the following.
Sub-claim 2. All boards simultaneously winning for $34, 45$ are of the form $1^{5k} + A$, where $A \in \{-, 1, 2^4, 1^42, 1^32^5\}$.
Sub-claim 3. All boards simultaneously winning for $23, 34, 45$ are of the form $1^{5k}$.
Since $1^{5k}$ is losing for the coalition $12$, the main claim follows.
Strange DAG game. We argue that position $14$ of this DAG is winning for all 2-player coalitions.
To change the mood of the answer a little bit, here's a strategic proof.

Starting at positions $1, 2, 3$, the losing player is forced.

Any 2-player coalition containing $1$ can win from any position among $4, 5, 6$. Indeed, $1$ is not in danger of being left with no moves. Choosing between two options of the remaining number of moves, he is able to save his partner from losing.

Position $7$ is winning exactly for those 2-player coalitions $C$ that contain either $1$ or $2$.

If $2 \in C$, he will win on the next move from any of $4, 5, 6$.
Otherwise, if $1 \in C$, he still can't be the one to lose in the end, so he can choose among $4, 5, 6$ to deprive the opposition of the only option that makes his partner lose.
Finally, if $1, 2 \not \in C$, the opposition forcibly wins by moving to position $1$ in 2 or 3 moves.


Any non-consecutive 2-player coalition wins from position $10$. The game will reach position $7$, and a non-consecutive coalition loses if it becomes $35$ by then. Depending on whether it takes 1 or 3 moves to get to position $7$, the potentially losing non-consecutive coalitions are $14$ and $13$, which can both avoid losing since they are on the move.

Still starting at position $10$, coalitions $12$ and $15$ win by choosing the correct route to $7$, and coalition $34$ will be happy to reach $7$ by any route to become either $23$ or $15$.

All 2-player coalitions except $45$ win starting at position $12$.

All non-consecutive coalitions will be happy to move through position $10$, and the only coalition unhappy to move through $7$ is $14$, who is luckily on the move.
All coalitions $12$, $23$, $34$ will by happy with the straight route to $7$, which $12$ is able to make happen. If the route goes to $10$ instead, $23$ and $34$ become $15$ and $12$ by then, and still win.
Coalition $15$ will prefer to go through $10$, becoming $34$ by then, which is a win.


Finally, all 2-player coalitions win starting from $14$. Coalitions in danger of becoming $45$ by the time position $12$ is reached are $15$ and $12$, which both can happily avoid it.



Here's a simpler presentation of a strange DAG game ("simpler" in the sense of "less words", it probably has more nodes). Each player, on their turn, chooses some other player. After every player has chosen, the losing player is the first player who is not in a pair of two players who both chose each other; such a player must exist because the number of players is odd. Each 2-player coalition is winning by simply both choosing each other. (We can choose who the losing player is by having a chain of forced moves of appropriate length before the game ends.)

@pastebee Good point, that is indeed much simpler, thank you! Not sure what I was going for when trying to find the smallest graph example, but here we are. I'll still leave it in for now.

The "strange DAG game" was actually the motivation for this question (although my own construction was basically @pastebee's comment): if the answer to this question is that no strange nim games exist, then Sprague-Grundy fails for more players in a particularly strong way.
